# Find Site from HTTP Request

Tags: http, web

Is there a way to go through a series of request and see what pages they are coming from?  I am getting all HTTP requests sent from my PC.  I am trying to see if there is a way in which I can just find out the main request.  Like if a page has images on it, when the images request is sent, is there a way to see if the images are coming from another page using just HTTP requests.  I don't know if I explained this well enough, so please ask any questions.  I don't know if there is a way to do this, but I hope there is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows: [Fiddler.](http://www.fiddler2.com/)

Comment: No, I already have the HTTP requests.  I am trying to see if they are original, or are coming from the same page(eg: images, jscript files, etc).  I just want to see which HTTP requests are coming straight from the user, not what other files the page is sub requesting, if there is way.

Comment: What do you mean by _"have the HTTP requests?"_ Do you mean that you have the raw text, like this: https://gist.github.com/1148398? You could check the [`Referer` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer), but be aware that it's trivial to spoof. (If not, what _do_ you mean?)

Comment: Yea, I have the raw text.  I thought referer would happen if you were on Google or something and then you clicked on a link?

Comment: Sure, that's what it might contain for the base page if you arrived via a link from another page (a la the example request I linked). But here's an example request for jQuery.js, requested because of a `<script>` tag in the page you're looking at right now: https://gist.github.com/1148413. (Note the caching-related headers are set as they are because I hard-refreshed the page so that the script would not be served from my browser's cache).

Comment: How could I get passed the link referer program?  or is there a way?

Comment: I beg your pardon? What are you talking about?

Comment: Yea, I messed that up.  Is there a way I can get passed the problem where like, lets say, I click a Google URL and it has google as the referer?  Really don't know how to explain this...